# ostringstream object creation causing my program to crash

Tags: c++

My program always crashes while creating an object of ostringstream class. I am unable to understand what is causing it to crash ?

## Program:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

DDF foo::send(const DDF& in)
{

    ostringstream os;  <-- causing crash always
    os << in;
    string ostr(os.str());
  ..
}

backtrace of the core
=================
Breakpoint 1, DDF foo::send (this=0x7244f48, in=@0x5496760) at foo.cpp:290
290 DDF foo::send(const DDF& in)
Current language:  auto; currently c++
(gdb) n
456     _M_streambuf(0), _M_ctype(0), _M_num_put(0), _M_num_get(0)
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f897cd7df9c in std::locale::_S_initialize () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f897cd7df9c in std::locale::_S_initialize () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007f897cd7e005 in std::locale::locale () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007f897de70760 in foo::send (this=0x7244f48, in=@0x7f897cd7df40)
    at /opt/gcc-4.3.2/lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.3.2/../../../../include/c++/4.3.2/bits/basic_ios.h:456
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a better compiler, like GCC 4.8.2 (or higher) or clang (latest is 3.5).